# how to define initializer for UIViewController when present or push programmatically by another UIViewController

Tags: swift

I'm using swift 4.2 in my project and I want to programmatically present or push ViewControllerB from ViewControllerA and send some data(for example numberOfSelectedMusics) from A to B.

ViewControllerB have super class(for example BaseViewController).

and I want to define property(numberOfSelectedMusics) as **let** (not **var**).

how I must declare initializer in ViewControllerB?

if I using **var** instead **let** for property I'm using this codes in ViewControllerB class:

```
class ViewControllerB: BaseViewController {

    private var numberOfSelectedMusics: String!
    convenience init(numberOfSelectedMusics: String) {

        self.init()

        self.numberOfSelectedMusics = numberOfSelectedMusics
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean custom initializer for a `ViewController` with **Storyboard** designed view?

Comment: No, not Storyboard. I want custom initializer programmatically